# Set RadioGroup selected RadioButton by value of String

Tags: android, kotlin, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

Since Kotlin does not support traditional for loop is there a way to select a RadioButton in a RadioGroup if the String x value matched the RadioButton text?

Something like this will work on Java but not in Kotlin

```
 for(i...radioGroup.childCount){
        int radioButtonID = radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        View radioButton = radioButtonGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
        int idx = radioButtonGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
    }
```

Then something like this code to select the correct radio based on String value

```
if(radioBtn.text.toString.equals("Sample"))
       radioBt.check(R.id.radio1);
    else 
       radioBt.check(R.id.radio2);
```

Comment: In your second snippet, what is `radioBtn` and which buttons do `R.id.radio1` and `R.id.radio2` represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rg - your radioGroup

```
for (rbPosition in 0 until rg.childCount) {
            val rb = rg.getChildAt(rbPosition) as RadioButton
            if (rb.text == yourText) {
                //do stuff for example rb.isChecked = true
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the radio buttons inside a radio group by using `radioGroup.children`.
And you can iterate over this collection similar to how @rost suggested.
A more functional way of finding the button can be:

```kotlin
val radioButton = radioGroup.children
                      .map { it as RadioButton } // Convert the sequence of Views to sequence of RadioButtons
                      .find { it.text == buttonText }!! // Don't use this !! if there's a possibility that no RadioButton with provided text exists

// Now you have the button, use it however you want
```

Comment: this is 2n solution for n problem

Comment: @rost Yeah, maybe in the worst case. `.children` returns a `Sequence` so the below operators are applied lazily. if the first button matches the terminal condition, other buttons will be just skipped. And here `n` will be at max 10 or 20 so `2n` and `n` don't matter much.

Comment: time complexity is considered for the worst case

Comment: Agreed, but how much performance gain do you think `n` has over `2n` when n is really small. It's more about readability than performance. I just provided an alternate way of finding the button (not saying that this is the best)

Comment: And you could just replace the above code with `radioGroup.children.find { it is RadioButton && it.text == buttonText}!! as RadioButton` if this looks like `n` to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better since it may have any views other than RadioButton.

```
val radioButton = radioGroup.children.filter {
        it is RadioButton && it.text == "YOUR STRING HERE"
    }.map {
        it as RadioButton
    }.firstOrNull()
    
radioButton?.let { 
        it.isChecked = true
    }
```